# Changing MVVM ListView SelectedItem in code throws 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

Tags: xaml, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 Universal App using the MVVM Light Toolkit.
I have a ListView

```
<ListView  
   x:Name="MyListView"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ModelCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"                              
   SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentModelItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

and my ViewModel is as it follows:

```
public class PageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> _modelCollection = 
        new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> ModelCollection 
    {
        get { return _modelCollection ; }
        set { Set(() => ModelCollection , ref _modelCollection , value); }
    }

    private MyViewModel _currentModelItem;
    public InspectionDiscrepancyViewModel CurrentModelItem
    {
        get { return _currentModelItem; }
        set { Set(() => CurrentModelItem, ref _currentModelItem, value); }
    }
```

If I let the CurrentModelItem item at load time it works 'fine' but if I try to set the CurrentModelItem in the LoadData Method -that populates the ObservableCollection- to the first ModelCollection Item

```
CurrentModel = ModelCollection.FirstOrDefault();
```

I get the following error on the Set() Method of the MVVM Light Toolkit:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

I've seen that doing this should be very straightforward, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From where are you calling the LoadData method?

Comment: @Bells I have a RelayCommand that is binded to the "Loaded" event of the page using Behaviours. When this command gets executed it calls the LoadDataAsync method that first loads the ModelCollection and then sets the CurrentModel.